# SQL Sub query from VB.net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I am working with some traffic data in VB.net using SQL database. My Data Table name [Sim VehRecord]. Columns are

1. Record ID
2. Simulation Sec(s)
3. Vehicle No
4. Link No
5. Lane No
6. Position (m)
7. Vehicle Count

Basing on the Column-3 and Column-6 I would like to fill Column-7. All rows will be individual record where as Column-7 will be aggregate function.

I intend to count all Unique vehicles within 15 m back and 15 forward of each Position (Columns-6). Sample of Traffic Data are given below:

```
Record ID---Sim Sec(s)---Vehicle No---Link No---Lane No---Posn(m)---Veh Count  
        1        0.80        2        74        1        13.42    
        2        0.80        3        74        2        12.88    
        3        0.80        4        2         1        2.90    
        4        1.00        1        73        1        17.97  
        5        1.00        2        74        1        17.73  
        6        1.00        3        74        2        17.22  
        7        1.00        4        2         1        7.22  
        8        1.20        1        73        1        22.42  
        9        1.20        2        74        1        22.04  
        10       1.20        3        74        2        21.57  
        11       1.20        4        2         1        11.54
```

I have used the following SQL code but that returned zero result. No error either.

```vb
Public str As String = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Main Data.mdf;Integrated Security=True"     
Public con As New SqlConnection(str)
Public SqlDataAdapter2 As New SqlDataAdapter
Public cmd4 As New SqlCommand
Public rdr As SqlDataReader

Public Sub GetDensity()
    SqlDataAdapter2.SelectCommand = cmd4
    cmd4.CommandText = "SELECT [Veh Count] = COUNT(DISTINCT t1.[Veh No]) 
                                FROM [Sim VehRecord] AS t1
                                INNER JOIN
                                [Sim VehRecord] AS t2
                                ON 
                                t1.[Record ID] = t2.[Record ID]
                                WHERE
                                t1.[Position (m)] > t2.[Position (m)] - 15
                                AND 
                                t1.[Position (m)] < t2.[Position (m)] + 15"

    cmd4.Connection = con
    Try
       con.Open()
       cmd4.ExecuteNonQuery()
       SqlDataAdapter2.UpdateCommand = cmd4
       rdr = cmd4.ExecuteReader()
       While rdr.Read
             MsgBox(rdr(0).ToString)
       End While
       cmd4.Dispose()
       con.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Any assistance will be appreciable. Also please advise is there any redundancy of code which is not required at all.

Comment: Please tag your RDBMS as *SQL database* is not specific enough. Oracle, Postgres, SQL Server, MySQL, DB2, and others run SQL so all fall under your definition.

Comment: Either you want to return records, then you need a SELECT query together with `ExecuteReader` (no `SqlDataAdapter` required), or you want modify records and need an [UPDATE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) query together with `ExecuteNonQuery`. Not sure what you want.

Comment: The specified Column values are null. I need to fill up the values basing on my conditions that i have mentioned

Comment: I intend to count all Unique vehicles within 15 m back and 15 forward of each Position (Columns-6).

Comment: Take some time and read this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251078/how-to-update-and-accept-answers/251399#251399

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To update records you need an SQL UPDATE statement. In this case

```sql
update [Sim VehRecord]
set [Vehicle Count] =
  (select count(distinct [Vehicle No])
   from [Sim VehRecord] sv
   where
       sv.[Position (m)] > [Sim VehRecord].[Position (m)] - 15 AND
       sv.[Position (m)] < [Sim VehRecord].[Position (m)] + 15
   );
```

Excecute it like this

```vb
Dim connectionString As String = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|..."
Dim connection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)

Dim cmd As SqlCommand = connection.CreateCommand()

Try
    connection.Open()

    '--- Update records
    cmd.CommandText = "update [Sim VehRecord] ..." 'Insert query from above
    Dim rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

    '--- Read records
    cmd.CommandText = "select * from [Sim VehRecord];"
    Dim rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    While rdr.Read
         MsgBox(rdr(0).ToString)
    End While
Catch ex As SqlException
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
Finally
    rdr.Dispose()
    cmd.Dispose()
    connection.Close()
End Try
```

See SQL example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/bf23a/1/0

To read the updated records you must execute a separate query and execute it with `ExecuteNonQuery`.

```sql
select * from [Sim VehRecord];
```

Comment: Maybe this helps: [How To Load Data From Database Into DataGridView In VB.NET](https://www.dotnetheaven.com/article/how-to-load-data-from-database-into-datagridview-in-vb.net). Note, your code is misleading, as you try to do all at once, update, read with a reader and fill a data adapter. You must do everything separately; however, you can use the same connection and reuse the same command object.

Comment: Showing messages boxes while connection is open. I don't think I would do that.

Comment: I guess you don't like Using blocks.

Comment: One more thing i am working on this problem.  Is it possible to find out the vehicle no of leader and follower for each row in separate two columns basing on the position?

Comment: at the same Sim Sec (time) at the same lane.. i want to find out the nearest Lead vehicle number ahead of  this vehicle number in a new column for each row.

Comment: I am trying this SQL command  ``` UPDATE [Sim VehRecord]
        SET [Veh no of Leader] =
        (SELECT [Veh No] 
        FROM (SELECT MIN (sv.[Position (m)]) FROM [Sim VehRecord] sv 
        WHERE
                                sv.[Lane No] = [Lane No] 
        And
                                sv.[Sim Time (sec)] = [Sim Time (sec)]))```

Comment: `... SELECT TOP 1 [Veh No] FROM ... WHERE sv.[Position (m)] > [Sim VehRecord].[Position (m)] AND other conditions ORDER BY sv.Position DESC` and `... SELECT TOP 1 [Veh No] FROM ... WHERE sv.[Position (m)] < [Sim VehRecord].[Position (m)] AND other conditions ORDER BY sv.Position ASC`

Comment: Outstanding.. Thank a lot Olivier. I am now working on difference of position between leader vehicle no and Vehicle no for each row (if leader vehicle no is not null). If i fail then i will seek your help again. Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry Olivier.. I have failed again.. I have tried this code... no error.. but no result either. "  UPDATE [Sim VehRecord]
SET [Headway (m)] =
(SELECT ([Position (m)] - sv.[Position (m)]) FROM [Sim VehRecord] sv 
WHERE 
sv.[Veh no of Leader] is not Null
AND 
[Position (m)] IN
(SELECT [Position (m)] FROM [Sim VehRecord]
WHERE
[Sim VehRecord].[Veh No] = sv.[Veh no of Leader] 
AND 
[Sim VehRecord].[Sim Time (sec)] = sv.[Sim Time (sec)]
AND
[Sim VehRecord].[Lane No]= sv.[Lane No]))"

Comment: It is easier if you do it directly instead of doing a detour over the vehicle no.

`UPDATE [Sim VehRecord]
    SET [Headway (m)] = (
        SELECT MIN(sv.[Position (m)] - [Sim VehRecord].[Position (m)])
        FROM
            [Sim VehRecord] sv
        WHERE
            sv.[Position (m)] > [Sim VehRecord].[Position (m)]
    )`

Comment: Another thing. Post a new question instead of adding to the old one, when you have another question.

Comment: Thanks Olivier.. You above SQL for determining Headway between the vehicle and the leader vehicle is ok but giving all 0.00  result.  Should i not mention the other conditions like  .... sv.[Veh No]= [Sim VehRecord].[Veh no of Leader]
AND
sv.[Lane No] = [Sim VehRecord].[Lane No]
AND
sv.[Sim Time (sec)]= [Sim VehRecord].[Sim Time (sec)]  ". Next time i will post new question instead on adding to old one.

Comment: My update statement has no `[Veh no of Leader]`. The one with the closest position is returned. This is automatically the leader. You may need to compare the lanes as well. Don't know about Sim Time. If there is a `sv.[Position (m)] > [Sim VehRecord].[Position (m)]` then it should return a result > 0.  Have you done the subtraction right? I mean subtract the position of one table from the position of the **other** table.

Comment: I have used `(SELECT MIN(sv.[Position (m)] - [Position (m)])` instead of  your one `(SELECT MIN(sv.[Position (m)] - [Sim VehRecord].[Position (m)])`  due to error "Multiple columns are specified in an aggregated expression containing an outer reference. If an expression being aggregated contains an outer reference, then that outer reference must be the only column referenced in the expression."

Comment: My final code becomes    `UPDATE [Sim VehRecord] 
       SET [Headway (m)] = 
       (SELECT MIN(sv.[Position (m)] - [Position (m)]) 
       FROM [Sim VehRecord] sv 
       WHERE sv.[Position (m)] > [Sim VehRecord].[Position (m)]
       AND
       sv.[Lane No] = [Sim VehRecord].[Lane No]
                            AND
       sv.[Sim Time (sec)] = [Sim VehRecord].[Sim Time (sec)])`     but all results return "0.00"

Comment: My fault I dropped the table name `[Sim VehRecord]`. So it takes `sv` instead. Corrected:`MIN(sv.[Position (m)] - [Sim VehRecord].[Position (m)])`

Comment: But Olivier...`(SELECT MIN(sv.[Position (m)] - [Sim VehRecord].[Position (m)])` shows this error  "Multiple columns are specified in an aggregated expression containing an outer reference. If an expression being aggregated contains an outer reference, then that outer reference must be the only column referenced in the expression."

Comment: So take the outer reference out of the nested SELECT, like `UPDATE [Sim VehRecord] SET [Headway (m)] = (SELECT MIN(sv.[Position (m)]) FROM ... WHERE ...) - [Sim VehRecord].[Position (m)]`

Comment: Thanks Olivier.. It works absolutely fine now for me...Thanks a lot. You are so nice.. See you in next new post. Regards.